# Ошибка в конструкторе

Tags: java

Пишу свой список. Код неправильно работает, при добавление первого элемента.

```
public void add(Element f) {
    count++;
    if (head != null) {
        Element temp = head;
        while (temp.next != null) {
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        Element tempnew = new Element();
        tempnew.next = temp.next;
        temp.next = tempnew;
        temp.values = f;
    } else {
        head = new Element();
        head.values = f;
        temp = head;
    }
}
```

Comment: @retry, телепаты в отпуске, объясните конкретно, что работает неправильно. Программа шлем вам Exception? Элемент не добавляется?

Comment: а ошибки где? причем тут конструктор?  первый цикл while какой то сомнительный

Comment: первый элемент просто не добавляется.
Со следующими все нормально

Comment: @retry, если первый элемент не добавляется, то как могут добавляться остальные? Первый не добавился, значит следующий, который вы пытаетесь вставить, будет опять же первым, и он тоже не вставится.

Comment: Как это вообще компилируется? Каким образом в ветке `else` виден `temp`?

Answer (score 2):

Что здесь происходит? Почему add принимает на вход Elements? Разве Elements - это не звено списка?? Или вы пытаетесь сделать какой-то список списков?

В любом случае, добавление первого элемента похоже должно сработать.

```
tempnew.next = temp.next;
```

Зачем? Мы ведь только что добились чтобы temp.next = null с помощью цикла выше.

Как вы используете temp в случае head = null ?? Откуда взялась тут эта переменная? Она ведь не будет доступна. И зачем мы её присваиваем в конце?

Что-то вы тут странное нам даёте...

Comment: похоже не на ответ, а на кучу вопросов :)

Comment: Правильно поставленные вопросы часто уже и есть половина ответов.